# No $_POST variables

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

I am using *Smarty* as a template engine, *wamp* server and I have a problem submitting a form in that no `$_POST` variables are being submitted.

If I comment out the *jQuery* (v1.11.1 as that was the version packaged with the jQuery ui custom theme the pages are built with) or the *jQuery-mobile* then the variables work. If I switch to 3.4.1 then the variables are posted but the themes now don't work (evidently doesn't recognise the classes).

This is a cut down version of the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./script/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="./controlA.php?action=do_login" name="loginForm">

            <label>Email :</label>
            <input type="text" name="loginEmail" id="loginEmail">

            <label>Password :</label>
            <input type="password" name="loginPassword" id="loginPassword">

            <input type="submit" name="submitLogin" id="submitLogin" value="Login">

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And for the controller:

```
session_start();
require_once('./smartylibs/Smarty.class.php');

$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->setTemplateDir('./smarty/templates');
$smarty->setCompileDir('./smarty/templates_c');
$smarty->setCacheDir('./smarty/cache');
$smarty->setConfigDir('./smarty/configs');


if (isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
    $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
} else {
    $action = 'no_action';
}

switch($action) {
    case "do_login":
        do_login($smarty);
        break;
    case "no_action":
        no_action_view($smarty);
        break;
    default:
        default_view($smarty);
}

function no_action_view($smarty) {
    $smarty->display('no_action.tpl');
}

function do_login($smarty) { 
    var_dump($_POST);
    exit;
}
```

Running the code as written above results in the following `var_dump` (but only after a page refresh):

```
C:\wamp64\www\CA\controlA.php:42: array (size=0)   empty
```

There are no events that I can see on page inspection.

Commenting out `<script src="./script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>` gives:

```
C:\wamp64\www\CA\controlA.php:42: array (size=3)   'loginEmail' =>
string 'email' (length=5)   'loginPassword' => string 'pass'
(length=4)   'submitLogin' => string 'Login' (length=5)
```

You get the same result if I use 3.4.1 but that creates errors with the styling. If I need to I will rebuild everything with new jQuery ui but if someone can spot what is going on that would be even better.

If I just use a normal page redirect (i.e. `action="./page.php"`) with a `var_dump()` there it also outputs the `$_POST` variables correctly so I have no idea if the problem is using `$_GET` in the `?action=do_login` at the same time.

The file structure which will result in the error is:

```
controlA.php
login_test.php
script/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min
script/jquery-1.11.1.min
```

and then the *smartylibs* folder (as it was downloaded, full of only *php* files) and *smarty* (which contains the four subfolders required in the script but otherwise empty). It would seem that something in the smartylibs is conflicting with the jquery.

Comment: So just to summarise: using jquery 3.4.1, redirect to new page in form action (not $_GET), and commenting out jquery 1.11.1 result in the $_POST variable working as expected.

Comment: Where is your jQuery?

Comment: You'll have to show the contents of functions.js. If the form data never even reaches the server, the PHP code is irrelevant. You have something that intercepts the form submission in the JS code.

Comment: Do you mean post all of "jquery-1.11.1.min.js"?

Comment: ...no. *The contents of functions.js.*

Comment: Apologies, was replying directly to GrumpyCrouton. There is nothing in the functions.js file that affects this code - it is just four functions that display or hide specific divs. Only the jquery has any effect on the code.

Comment: The mere jQuery library files don’t _do_ anything to your page or how it behaves on their own. Some JS code must be interfering with your form submission, but with the code shown so far, rather impossible to tell what and where. (And your HTML does not really contain _two_ `body` elements, that’s only a mess-up while posting the code here, right …?)

Comment: Yes, error in pasting. The issues occur with just four files plus the contents of the smartylibs folder which only contains php files. The only js file that appears to effect the action is jquert-1.11.1.min. If it helps, I'm using wamp as the server.

Comment: @misorude — jQuery doesn't, I think jQuery mobile does all kinds of hijacking though.

Comment: @Quentin - yes, just tested that and also commenting out the jquery-mobile also results in the code working correctly.

Comment: @Quentin you’re right, according to https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/forms/forms-sample.html it tries to hook into all forms that have action and method set, to submit them via AJAX automatically. Not sure how a different jQuery version makes a difference regarding that though, with a more complex form I’d expect maybe a different default for the ajax `traditional` setting could have an effect, but this one is very basic, so that should not apply here.

Comment: _“so I have no idea if the problem is using $_GET in the ?action=do_login at the same time”_ - should not be with normal form submission, but maybe with jQuery mobile it is in this situation. Can you replace that with a hidden field to submit that action value, and see if that changes anything? (You’re picking it out of `$_REQUEST['action']` on the server side, so whether this gets send as a GET or POST parameter would make no difference on the receiving end here anyway.)

Comment: With jquery not commented,   '$_REQUEST' => array (size=1) 'action' => string 'do_login' (length=8). With jquery commented out,   '$_REQUEST' => 
    array (size=5)
      'action' => string 'do_login' (length=8)
      'loginEmail' => string 'email' (length=5)
      'loginPassword' => string 'pass' (length=4)
      'hidden' => string 'HIDDEN' (length=6)
      'submitLogin' => string 'Login' (length=5)